# where does the hive runs and role of JVM

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, hive

Im having a small doubt. I  have been reading about HIVE. And i have the below question in my mind

```
Whether HIVE runs on java virtual machine (JVM) ?
```

I have googled but i couldnot find any answer . Can any one explain me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All Hive components are Java code that runs on JVM. That includes HiveServer, HiveServer2, metastore, Hive CLI, query processing, pretty much everything. For all practical purposes you can't run Java code without a JVM.